# Not able to run selenium script through testng

Tags: java, xml, selenium

I have written a simple script in selenium. I am using Testng. I created a xml file where I mentioned suit name and class name. Xml file code is as

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name='Suit1' verbose="3" parallel="methods">
    <test name="Wiki">
        <classes>
            <class name="additional.wikipediaTEst"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Now when I try to run this by right clicking inside xml file, text box for selecting suite is disabled.

How this would be enable.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Yes I am using Eclipse IDE

Comment: I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install **TestNG** Eclipse Plugin. It can be installed from **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace ->** Search for **TestNG** and **Install**. After install it will ask to restart Eclipse. After restart, you should see the option to run the testng xml file as TestNG.

Hope it helps!

Comment: ya its working now. Actually i removed first line from xml file i.e <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> then its start detecting xml file.

Comment: Good to know. Accept the correct answer if that helped you anyway.

Comment: You can accept answer by clicking on the big tick mark placed for the answer. Please see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png